# C++ Memory leaks form inserting data into linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, linked-list

I'm required to use either unique_ptr or shared_ptr for my linked list, but I am still getting memory leaks. Just for this case, I'm leaving all the member data as `public`. Inserting the first time into the linked list does not cause any memory leaks, but as the for loop continues, each time I insert an object as the data into the linked list, the debugger shows more memory leaks. I don't know what could be causing so many memory leaks. Could it be caused by some of the shared ptrs?

```
    template <typename T>
    class Node
    {
    public:
       T data;
       shared_ptr<Node<T>> next;
       shared_ptr<Node<T>> prev;

    public:
       Node() { next = NULL; prev = NULL; data = 0; }
       Node(T value) { next = NULL; prev = NULL; data = value; }
       T getData() { return data; }

    };

  template <typename T>
  class DoubleLinkedList
  {
  public:
      shared_ptr<Node<T>> head;
      shared_ptr<Node<T>> tail;
  public:
      DoubleLinkedList()
     {
         head = NULL;
         tail = NULL;
         total = 100;
         for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
         {
            Insert(objectgetsinsertedhere);
         }
     }


void Insert(T data)
{
    shared_ptr<Node<T>> rover = NULL;
    T value(data);
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = make_shared<Node<T>>(data);
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        shared_ptr<Node<T>> nu = make_shared<Node<T>>(data);
        nu->prev = tail;
        if (head == tail)
            head->next = nu;
        tail->next = nu;
        tail = nu;
    }
}
};
```

EDIT: This is a portion of what the debugger shows as memory leaks.

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{211} normal block at 0x005CF798, 8 bytes long.
Data: <x \     > 78 98 5C 00 00 00 00 00 
{210} normal block at 0x005CF258, 8 bytes long.
Data: <\ \     > 5C 98 5C 00 00 00 00 00 
{209} normal block at 0x005CF1B0, 8 bytes long.
Data: <@ \     > 40 98 5C 00 00 00 00 00 
{205} normal block at 0x005C9830, 136 bytes long.
Data: <H               > 48 A9 0C 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 
{191} normal block at 0x005CF3A8, 8 bytes long.
Data: <  \     > A8 DB 5C 00 00 00 00 00 
{190} normal block at 0x005CF0D0, 8 bytes long.
Data: <  \     > 8C DB 5C 00 00 00 00 00 
{189} normal block at 0x005CF060, 8 bytes long.
Data: <p \     > 70 DB 5C 00 00 00 00 00 
{185} normal block at 0x005CDB60, 136 bytes long.
Data: <H               > 48 A9 0C 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
```

Comment: What exactly is the debugger reporting? (Is memory actually being leaked, or is it merely detecting more memory that expected?) If so, then it might be the shared_ptr that is causing this false positive as it requires memory itself in order to manage its pointer and synchronize all shared_ptr pointing to the same object.

Comment: This is what some of it looks like                                                    Dumping objects ->
{211} normal block at 0x005CF798, 8 bytes long.
{189} normal block at 0x005CF060, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <p \     > 70 DB 5C 00 00 00 00 00 
{185} normal block at 0x005CDB60, 136 bytes long.
 Data: <H               > 48 A9 0C 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have an ownership cycle in your shared pointers.  This makes it where the memory does not get freed automatically because there is always at least one owner, even after the linked list itself has been destroyed.  One way to address this is to only use a shared pointer for the next pointer, but not the prev pointer:

```
template <typename T>
class Node
{ 
  public:
    T data;
    shared_ptr<Node<T>> next;
    Node<T> *prev;

  public:
    Node() { next = NULL; prev = NULL; data = 0; } 
    Node(T value) { next = NULL; prev = NULL; data = value; }
    T getData() { return data; }

};
```

This prevents the ownership cycle.  The list owns the head, the head owns the second element, etc.  When the list is destroyed, then there are no owners for the head, so the head gets destroyed, and now there are no owners for the second element, so it gets destroyed, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm only allowed to either use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`. Do you think another way to address this is to use a unique pointer for the prev pointer and a shared pointer for the next pointer?

Comment: Also, changing it to two different pointers will cause an error to insert the nodes for example `nu->prev = tail;` will give an error of "cannot convert from shared_ptr to Node<T>*"

Comment: In that case you need to write a destructor.

Comment: @Mark: No, they are not interchangeable.  If you can't use any raw pointers, then I think you would have to manually detach your nodes when you destroy your DoubleLinkedList.  I doubt that is what is intended.  Are you sure the requirement is to never use a raw pointer?

Comment: @Mark.  You can use `tail.get()` to get a raw pointer from your shared_ptr.

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes, my professor wants us to only use smart pointers, the requirements says to "Replace all the Node<T>* with either unique_ptr<T> or shared_ptr<T>."

Comment: @Mark: It is possible to get rid of your memory leak by doing more work in the destructor, but it won't happen automatically.

Comment: @VaughnCato   How would the destructor work? Would I make a raw pointer point to the head, and keep moving to each node and delete?

Comment: @Mark: Just do the reverse of what you did for an insert.

Comment: @VaughnCato What do you mean do the reverse? Do you mean it is like the insert, but I need a `Node<T>*` to point to the `nu` and `prev` and `tail` to delete each node?

Comment: @Mark: Instead of inserting, you are removing.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list#Removing_a_node  Also make sure that  you set the next and prev to nullptr on the node you remove.

Comment: @VaughnCato In the destructor, since I will be removing will I be using any `delete` or I am just detaching the nodes?

Comment: @Mark: Because you are using shared_ptrs.  The nodes will be deleted as soon as nothing points to them.

Comment: @VaughnCato I think I understand it now. By setting each node's next and prev to nullptr, each node will then be deleted since nothings points to them?

Comment: @VaughnCato Do I have to worry about `shared_ptr<Node<T>> nu`? That's in the insert function, so I'm not sure what I can do with it in the destructor.

Comment: @Mark: Since it is a local variable, it is destroyed automatically, so you don't have to worry about it.